# PHP сортировка не связанных переменных

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Подскажите во что объединить переменные что бы потом их отсортировать. Пробовал смотреть на массивы многомерные, но вообще не понял что там к чему.

Ситуация такая: Парсю по порядку XML фиды магазинов и складываю в переменные:

```
//Магазин 1
foreach ($goodsteam->xpath('rows/row') as $element) {
    if (stripos($element->name_goods, $game) === false) continue;
    $title = $element->name_goods;
    $price = $element->price;
    $discount = $element->discount;

//Магазин 2
foreach ($playo->xpath('/playocards/playocard') as $element) {
    if (stripos($element->title, $game) === false) continue;
    $title = $element->title;
    $price = $element->price;
    $discount = $element->disount;

//Магазин 3
foreach ($steambuy->xpath('/steambuy.response/response/data/goods') as $element) {
    if (stripos($element->name, $game) === false) continue;
    $title = $element->name;
    $price = $element->price->rub;
}
```

Нужно между парсингом магазинов сохранять куда-то результат, чтобы потом отсортировать по цене и вывести таблицу на странице.

Подскажите как бы вы это сделали?

Comment: В массив, а потом пройтись функцией сортировки. Советую вам разобраться что там и к чему

Comment: Добавляю элементы в массив вот так $array[] = array($element->name_goods, $element->price, $element->discount, $element->id_goods, ''); а вот как его потом отсортировать?

Comment: На выбор `uasort()`  `uksort()` `usort()`. Придумываете какую угодно сортировочную функцию